# How to get tinybutstrong mergeblock with condition working for empty value

Tags: tinybutstrong

I am using tinybutstrong as a templating engine.

I am trying to get the active link to display in a different color.

The following is my (trimmed down) PHP side:

```
$links = array (
    '' => 'Home',
    'about' => 'About Us',
    'faq' => 'FAQ',
    'contact' => 'Contact Us',
);
$uri = substr($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], 1);
$TBS->MergeBlock('blkLinks', 'array', $links);
```

Html Template:

```
<ul>
    <li><a href="/[blkLinks.$;block=li]" style="[onshow;if [onload.uri]=[blkLinks.$]; then 'color:#86AD6D;']">[blkLinks.val;]</a></li>
</ul>
```

While it generates the html fine and nicely changes the color of the links when that page is currently active, this does not work for the empty (/) link.

How can I fix that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply replace the condition

```
[onload.uri]=[blkLinks.$]
```

with

```
'[onload.uri]'='[blkLinks.$]'
```

The point is that when [onload.uri] is an emprty string, then the expression can be ambiguous. Using the string delimitors, the expression is clear for TBS.